Why is email I send to Gmail is not being received?
When I send an email to a Gmail contact, it does not arrive. I know there are specific domain records for authentication.
I've used cPanel to check email deliverability and it reports that the relevant records, DKIM, SPF and PTR, are correct.
Here are the TXT records.
DKIM:
v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAoqaJw5FM1RQgIECSaN8T8v7bzvVWi/ydRRTad39MawDQ+SjVLd+EOOJ/d48YGWUoOq8Jh03/vxlh4s5z/Eq/APC/DuPZLZR5IregyrWzWrhCJyiRqe0zc3NKaQg4AOFNkFJovMoIiWgLSPwoAB3EWJhgAe1MLislv8ZdIyuxRMOmCVd9nEkYCRmhJ5J/m13F4h9az6kL9y3kOqdolB7KSY07Sgcx/uGN4WPSIBQXwhlEX6UB1tIVKYzUBkp/hgUUY3PmY+kBW+/YP9gnsnbi8qdNI/X0FJ0ycfaQ+vz655rrJyrMDUqihVhIgw3OlNYNc+4ICUkrZtDxlNEsPs9KHQIDAQAB;

SPF:
v=spf1 a mx include:websitewelcome.com ~all

PTR:
gator4180.hostgator.com.

Is there any other way to check this? Does Gmail, for example, provide a way to check a domain's deliverability? I've been at this for a while and haven't found a way to fix this.

How is the message being sent? Operating system? Is GMail blacklisting you? Add answers to questions and tags.

Low cost hosting services will often have intermittent issues with server/IP reputation as a result of the sheer volume of accounts and the fact a small subset spin up the accounts for SPAM purposes and worse.
One thing you can do is to add your domain to Google Postmaster Tools.  This Google tool helps domain owners determine how Google sees their sending mail domain.
You must have a Google account, either Personal or Google Workspace, in order to use the tool.
Resources

   Google

Email sender guidelines
Set up Postmaster Tools
Sign in to Postmaster Tools  


   Hostgator

Google - New Authentication Requirements for Email Senders
Changing DNS Zones in cPanel



  

Excerpts below from: Set up Postmaster Tools
Set up Postmaster Tools
Monitor outgoing email to Gmail accounts
Use Postmaster Tools to monitor information about outgoing email that you send to personal Gmail accounts, and about the domains and IP addresses you use to send email. The information in Postmaster Tools helps you meet Gmail’s requirements for sending email to personal Gmail accounts, described in our Email sender guidelines and Email sender guidelines FAQ.
Postmaster Tools dashboards have detailed information about spam rate, reputation, message authentication, and delivery errors. For details about each dashboard, visit Postmaster Tools dashboards.
Step 1: Add your sending domain to Postmaster Tools

Sign in to Postmaster Tools
In the bottom right, click Add 
In the Getting started window, enter the domain used to authenticate your outgoing email with SPF, or DKIM, or both. If you use different domains for SPF and DKIM authentication, you only need to enter one of these domains.
Click Next to open the Verify your domain window.

Step 2: Verify your sending domains
You can skip this step and continue setup without verifying your domain, but Postmaster Tools won’t display information about your email until your domain is verified. To skip this step, click Not now.
You’ll log into your domain provider’s management console in this step, so you may want to open it in another browser tab.

In the Verify your domain window, copy the text in the TXT record field.
Log into your domain provider and add the copied text to your domain’s DNS records. For detailed steps, visit Verify your domain (host-specific steps).
Return to the Verify your domain window and click Verify.
Typically domains are verified right away but it might take up to 10 minutes before your domain’s verification status is updated.
After you click Verify or Not now, the domain appears on the Postmaster Tools domains page.

